# Good practice in DB connection

Tags: database, delphi

I am creating Delphi app to connect with my db.

In some occasions my app needs to write multiple entries in a second , in other time it has to starve for some minutes.

so it is pointless to open and close connection always, or to keep open for hours.

> So i thought about creating a timer(interval = 1000), and the timer
>   will decrease an integer from 10 to 0 on every ticks. when the int is
>   0 connection will be closed.
>
> every method that interacts with the db will run another method which
>   will set the int to 10 and check whether the connection is open , if not it will open the connection
>   .

Is this a good practice in db handling , or is there any other suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify these considerations 1) What Connection component do you use? 2) Are you targeting entreprise application? Thank you.

Comment: I am using mysql , and it is a simple app (not enterprise level)

Comment: , component is tmysqlconnection

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The DB's have differently "wheighted" connections. Eg, MySQL API allows to open a connection fast, comparing to Oracle OCI. So, with MySQL you can open a connection, do whatever you need, close connection. The open / close times will be unnoticable.
2. The DB's have different connection timeouts. Eg, when MySQL connection is inactive longer than `wait_timeout` / `interactive_timeout`, then MySQL server will automatically close the connection. And Oracle will keep your connection open as long as you need. So, the application must be capable to handle that.
3. The question is about resources. If there will be 10K clients, all keeping connections opeb, then this may overload the server by idle but allocated resources.
4. And the question is about application complexity. If it has to keep many datasets active, maintain active transactions, etc. Then it will be quite hard to reopen a connection.
5. Also, some data access components, like [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/), allow to automatically recover a connection ([more](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/unified-api.html#recovery)), when it is closed by DBMS or how else is losted.

So, basing on your DBMS, data access components, application needs, you have to decide what to do. Eg:

- with MySQL, 1-2 clients, simple inserts, and multi-minutes inactive lags, I will open connection before it is needed and will close it after the work is done;
- with Oracle, 1K clients, etc, I will use the algorythm, like your described.

Comment: Oracle can be configured to use the "shared server" mode (plus connection pooling and session multiplexing) when there are many connections which don't use the database all the time. The method suggested by the OP will just duplicate in a worse way what's already available. From a client perspective the session stays open (no need to reinitialize it), while the server will save resources.

Comment: Yes, correct, many things may be configured from the server side. Still to close connection, when it is not needed is a good practice. Similar to call .Free, when an object is not needed.

Comment: I agree connection could be closed when not needed, but that should be a "deterministic call" like .Free, not a timer that fires sometimes. The cost of reinitializing all DB-depentend objects should be also considered. IMHO if there is a proper configuration to allow for persistent connection while not impacting server performance/resource usage it should be considered before trying other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To my opinion, if your application user activity doesn't imply heavy connect/disconnect operations there is no need to add more complexity.